# How to get all parent nodes but filter child node in python django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I am trying to fetch all parent's records with child models with filtration in Django(3.2).

```
class Parent(models.Modal):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Child(models.Modal):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children", 
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_working = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[(1, 1), 
                             (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)])
```

just like these models I want to get all parents with not working children's.
i am trying like this `Parent.objects.filter(children__is_working=False)`. but get those parent who has is_working False value. if one parent has multiple children who have both
kinds of records so parent queryset returns those parents also.
my requirement is to get all parents with those children whose is_working value is False.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want parents with those children dont have is_working True so use exclude rather than filter:

```
Parent.objects.exclude(children__is_working=True)
```

Comment: thanks for this. but what if I am querying to a string field. then how we exclude or filter children. like in children model has another filed `level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)])
` then how to get level 1 children to parent model. `Parent.objects.exclude(children__level=1)`

Comment: I think `Parent.objects.exclude(children__level__in=[2,3,4])` works as expected

Comment: it not works. I am doing `level = [i['level'] for i in Child.objects.exclude(level=1).values('level').annotate().order_by()]                                       Parent.objects.exclude(children__level__in=level)
` but not getting level 1 records